# Problemas al encriptar el password con la función password_hash

Tags: php, mysql, encriptación

Buenos días, tengo un problema al momento de encriptar el password con la función "password_hash".
Cuando agrego un usuario y guardo el password encriptado en la BD no se registra completo.
Ejemplo.

```
$upass  = password_hash("123456", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
la cadena => $2y$10$g9UDyWYMYoDB1RdhUddxpuGcVR/mNTOQ4Po4CrT9NR47RaetaKtgW
```

pero, cuando se guarda en la BD la cadena del password no se guarda completa, al revisar indica lo siguiente:

```
pass en la bd:  $2y$10$g9UDyWYMYoDB1RdhUddxpuGcVR/mNTOQ4Po4CrT9NR4
```

Incluso la longitud del campo en la tabla es de 255, superior a la cadena pero no logro entender el porque me está cortando la cadena.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Primero, verifica que el campo en el que insertas la contraseña encriptada tiene la capacidad para contener esa cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: Pregunta tonta para descartar... ¿Has probado un `var_dump($upass)` justo antes de la consulta para comprobar que no se altera durante la ejecución?

Comment: intenta cambiando el tipo de dato a TEXT para descartar que sea el tipo del campo

Comment: Con lo poco que expones es muy difícil sacar conclusiones de que está sucediendo, te recomendaría que edites ([edit]) la pregunta y añadas el resto del código implicado así como un `SHOW CREATE TABLE tu_tabla` de la tabla de destino.